# UIActivityIndicator in iOS5 is supposed to have a color option. How to implement this?

Tags: xcode, ios5, uiactivityindicatorview

In iOS5, there [appears to be an option](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html) ** to use the UIActivityIndicator with a color in place of the gray/white options of the past.

I cannot figure out how to implement this. Has anyone done this? and how?

Many thanks..

** this is a link to Apple's documentation on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign a UIColor to the color property:

```
activityIndicator.color = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: I know you are right - I just cannot get it to work.. I've amended my dumb question to show the code..

Comment: I thought I edited the comment above. You were spot on, so  many thanks. I was just letting the code slip through a switch/case statement that I'd forgotten to put in breaks... D'oh...